# RegEx catching character space character character group

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to write a RegEx expression to find the following:

Space character preceded by a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or ) following by two characters falling in to the following category a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or - or (; i.e. **char1-space-char2-char3**

```
char1 = [0-9 a-z A-Z )]
char2 = [0-9 a-z A-Z - ]
char3 = [0-9 a-z A-Z (]
```

For example:

cos(x) + sin(x){S}-0.3 * cos(x){S}k * sin(x) - z0{S}ke-1{S}-ke-3

where {S} would be spaces I want to catch

I am new to RegEx and from what I can find online I need to use look ahead and look behind, but I am not sure how to make sure how to catch **char-space-char-char** group.

So far I have this but its not working at all

```
[\w\d\)]([ ]{1})[\w\d-]
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: `[\da-z)]( )[\da-z-]*[\da-z(]` should work: https://regex101.com/r/dF7lU5/2

Comment: `[\da-z)]( )[\da-z-]*[\da-z(]` really worked beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the look around assertions, that will handle overlapping that you need.
Just use your same constructs, but wrap before/after space with the  look around
syntax.

`(?i)(?<=[\da-z)])[ ](?=[\da-z-][\da-z(])`

Expanded:

```
 (?i)                       # Case insensitive
 (?<= [\da-z)] )            # Lookbehind, alnum or ')'
 [ ]                        # Consume space
 (?= [\da-z-] [\da-z(] )    # Lookahead, alnum or '-' followed by alnum or '('
```

Comment: This works also, thank you. Very clear indeed, the only thing is that it does not select the group, but catches the space only. But thats not a problem and mostly due to me not being very clear in my initial question.

Comment: @user5059061 - Using assertions this way allows catching possibly more valid spaces because assertions don't consume characters. Example:  `A BC DE` would find  2 valid spaces _with_ assertions. Without assertions, it would find only 1. You could get by just using the last assertion and you can still capture inside assertions. Example:  `(?i)([\da-z)])[ ](?=([\da-z-])([\da-z(]))`